# Router IP address change

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ip-address, adsl-router

I wanted to use my old router as access point to extend range of my wifi in my house. My old routers model name is D-Link DSL-2877 AL and I access this router using `192.168.1.1` address initially.

As I go into the network setting and change it to `192.168.0.3` (as this is my third router on my network, so `0.3` denotes third floor), and press save , it reloads the page.

After then, neither I can access the wifi router setting with the `192.168.0.3` nor can I access it using the first one.

I check the router IP address using the `ipconfig` command, it shows a random 16 letter address with `192.168.1.1` below it.

What am I doing wrong, please help...

Comment: After changing the routers ip did you also change your computers ip-address to be in the 192.168.0.x range ? If you didn't, it is totally logical that you can't access it anymore after the change. By the way it would help if you added the ipconfig output to your question. We can't guess what it says and the details could be important to help you. You can edit your question and add that information.

Comment: Your 3rd AP (router) should be in the same subnet as router 1 (`192.168.1.1/24`) so...  try `192.168.1.3`. Make sure Dhcp is off on AP/ Router3 and that all Ethernet connections are made to the LAN ports ( WAN port should be unused)

Comment: My main router IP is 192.168.0.1 and second router (i.e. an Access point) IP is 192.168.0.2 and both are using same subnet i.e. 255.255.255.0 and whenever I change my third routers IP settings on the same 255.255.255.0 subnet with IP changing from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.0.3 ( with DHCP servers off) , it just reloads and I can't access the router anymore...